# StrengthJS password strength works when in one function but doesn't work when there is multiple functions

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have StrengthJS password strength in a function, and I have 2 other functions that are for the other forms in tabs. However I can only get one to function to run and have to comment out the other 2 functions. Why is this happening?
My functions are

```
    function CheckAdministratorPasswordStrength() {
    $("#txtPassword").strength({
        strengthClass: 'strength',
        strengthMeterClass: 'strength_meter',
        strengthButtonClass: 'button_strength',
        strengthButtonText: 'Show password',
        strengthButtonTextToggle: 'Hide Password'
    });
}
function CheckModeratorPasswordStrength() {
    $("#txtAdministrationManufacturerModeratorPassword").strength({
        strengthClass: 'strength',
        strengthMeterClass: 'strength_meter',
        strengthButtonClass: 'button_strength',
        strengthButtonText: 'Show password',
        strengthButtonTextToggle: 'Hide Password'
    });
}
function CheckDealerPasswordStrength() {
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerPassword").strength({
        strengthClass: 'strength',
        strengthMeterClass: 'strength_meter',
        strengthButtonClass: 'button_strength',
        strengthButtonText: 'Show password',
        strengthButtonTextToggle: 'Hide Password'
    });
}
```

and they are being called in my document.ready function and I should also let everyone know that these are in an external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the javascript library you are using. See [this issue report](https://github.com/aarondo/Strength.js/issues/17) from the github site for Strength.js.

Looks like another user suggested a fix for this. You could try applying their fix. Open up your `strength.js` file and change line 93 from:

```
thisid = this.$elem.attr('id');
```

to:

```
var thisid = this.$elem.attr('id');
```

I copied the `strength.js` file from github into the snippet below and made that change and it appears to be working properly for multiple password fields. Also, it looks like you are just specifying the default options, so instead of passing in all the default options, you can just call `.strength()` without passing any parameters and it will use the default options.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pw1').strength();
  $('#pw2').strength();
  $('#pw3').strength();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/aarondo/Strength.js/master/src/strength.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*!
   * strength.js
   * Original author: @aaronlumsden
   * Further changes, comments: @aaronlumsden
   * Licensed under the MIT license
   */
  ;
  (function($, window, document, undefined) {

    var pluginName = "strength",
      defaults = {
        strengthClass: 'strength',
        strengthMeterClass: 'strength_meter',
        strengthButtonClass: 'button_strength',
        strengthButtonText: 'Show Password',
        strengthButtonTextToggle: 'Hide Password'
      };

    // $('<style>body { background-color: red; color: white; }</style>').appendTo('head');

    function Plugin(element, options) {
      this.element = element;
      this.$elem = $(this.element);
      this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
      this._defaults = defaults;
      this._name = pluginName;
      this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

      init: function() {


        var characters = 0;
        var capitalletters = 0;
        var loweletters = 0;
        var number = 0;
        var special = 0;

        var upperCase = new RegExp('[A-Z]');
        var lowerCase = new RegExp('[a-z]');
        var numbers = new RegExp('[0-9]');
        var specialchars = new RegExp('([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])');

        function GetPercentage(a, b) {
          return ((b / a) * 100);
        }

        function check_strength(thisval, thisid) {
          if (thisval.length > 8) {
            characters = 1;
          } else {
            characters = -1;
          };
          if (thisval.match(upperCase)) {
            capitalletters = 1
          } else {
            capitalletters = 0;
          };
          if (thisval.match(lowerCase)) {
            loweletters = 1
          } else {
            loweletters = 0;
          };
          if (thisval.match(numbers)) {
            number = 1
          } else {
            number = 0;
          };

          var total = characters + capitalletters + loweletters + number + special;
          var totalpercent = GetPercentage(7, total).toFixed(0);

          if (!thisval.length) {
            total = -1;
          }

          get_total(total, thisid);
        }

        function get_total(total, thisid) {

          var thismeter = $('div[data-meter="' + thisid + '"]');
          if (total <= 1) {
            thismeter.removeClass();
            thismeter.addClass('veryweak').html('very weak');
          } else if (total == 2) {
            thismeter.removeClass();
            thismeter.addClass('weak').html('weak');
          } else if (total == 3) {
            thismeter.removeClass();
            thismeter.addClass('medium').html('medium');

          } else {
            thismeter.removeClass();
            thismeter.addClass('strong').html('strong');
          }

          if (total == -1) {
            thismeter.removeClass().html('Strength');
          }
        }





        var isShown = false;
        var strengthButtonText = this.options.strengthButtonText;
        var strengthButtonTextToggle = this.options.strengthButtonTextToggle;


        var thisid = this.$elem.attr('id');

        this.$elem.addClass(this.options.strengthClass).attr('data-password', thisid).after('<input style="display:none" class="' + this.options.strengthClass + '" data-password="' + thisid + '" type="text" name="" value=""><a data-password-button="' + thisid + '" href="" class="' + this.options.strengthButtonClass + '">' + this.options.strengthButtonText + '</a><div class="' + this.options.strengthMeterClass + '"><div data-meter="' + thisid + '">Strength</div></div>');

        this.$elem.bind('keyup keydown', function(event) {
          thisval = $('#' + thisid).val();
          $('input[type="text"][data-password="' + thisid + '"]').val(thisval);
          check_strength(thisval, thisid);

        });

        $('input[type="text"][data-password="' + thisid + '"]').bind('keyup keydown', function(event) {
          thisval = $('input[type="text"][data-password="' + thisid + '"]').val();
          console.log(thisval);
          $('input[type="password"][data-password="' + thisid + '"]').val(thisval);
          check_strength(thisval, thisid);

        });



        $(document.body).on('click', '.' + this.options.strengthButtonClass, function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          thisclass = 'hide_' + $(this).attr('class');




          if (isShown) {
            $('input[type="text"][data-password="' + thisid + '"]').hide();
            $('input[type="password"][data-password="' + thisid + '"]').show().focus();
            $('a[data-password-button="' + thisid + '"]').removeClass(thisclass).html(strengthButtonText);
            isShown = false;

          } else {
            $('input[type="text"][data-password="' + thisid + '"]').show().focus();
            $('input[type="password"][data-password="' + thisid + '"]').hide();
            $('a[data-password-button="' + thisid + '"]').addClass(thisclass).html(strengthButtonTextToggle);
            isShown = true;

          }



        });




      },

      yourOtherFunction: function(el, options) {
        // some logic
      }
    };

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
      return this.each(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
          $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
        }
      });
    };

  })(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
<label for="pw1">Password 1:</label>
<input id="pw1" type="password" name="" value="">
<label for="pw2">Password 2:</label>
<input id="pw2" type="password" name="" value="">
<label for="pw3">Password 3:</label>
<input id="pw3" type="password" name="" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks for getting this cleared up, doesn't really matter if the show/hide password works or not, I can work around that.

Comment: The reason why the Show/Hide doesn't seem to work is because the inputs for the password type needed to be "password" then the Show/Hide works.

Comment: Ah, silly mistake. Updated my answer for anyone else that views this question. Show/hide password now works, but it shows/hides all of the passwords rather than just the one you click the button for. Overall, it is functional now though, with the one-line fix in the strength.js.